# Mobile Power Bank 18650 Battery Charger

Tags: batteries, mobile

My question is about the below power bank charging module. We connect 3.7V 18650 type batteries to this module. Then the output voltage of this module via USB is 5V. My question is how it returns 5V using 3.7V batteries.

[image]

Here is the product link :
[Mobile Power Bank Module](https://www.banggood.com/Dual-USB-5V-1A-2_1A-Mobile-Power-Bank-18650-Battery-Charger-PCB-Module-Board-p-1031593.html?rmmds=category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic question and you really should have put a little more effort in finding the answer yourself.

Anyway, it uses a [Boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter)

See the black/red copper component at the back, that's an inductor. It is an essential component in any switched converter.